# pandas df from a dictionary of list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of a two-elements list and I would like to transform it into a 3 columns pandas df.

This dict

```
    {
'Abg': [2, 0],
'Aidi': [1, 2],
'Geng': [0, 0],
}
```

into this df

```
0    1    2
Arg  2    0
Aidi 1    2
Geng 0    0
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items(name_dict.items(), 
                        orient='index', 
                        columns=['A','B'])
```